# Automaic resize watermark image when applying watermark on image

Tags: meteor, watermark

i tried to apply watermark on image using this watermark.js `http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/` .

here is my html code

```
<img class="watermark" src="/image/myImage.png" height="42" width="42" />
```

and my watermark.js initialization is :

```
wmark.init({
                "opacity": 50,
                "className": "watermark",
                "path": "/img/watermark.png"
            });
```

this is applying watermark when i'm not applying  `height="42" width="42"` on image tag.

when applying height and width it does not show watermark because of this height and width.

so my problem is i want to apply watermark image based on  `height="42" width="42"`. this watermark.js should apply automatically height and width depends on canvas image size.

can anyone do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a website of free coding chimps. Instead of asking someone to do something for you, try to do it, and come back to us when you've ran into issues you haven't managed to solve despite some searches =)

Comment: why don't you just resize your watermark to that size in an image editor?

Comment: because i want to apply dynamically depends on image height and width.